# layout_below does not work because of custom view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I have a custom view (`MyView`) which extends `SurfaceView` in which I override the `onDraw` method. I create an instance of this view dynamically with a custom constructor:

```
MyView myView = new MyView(...);
```

In this constructor I call the `super(Context context)` method.

After that, I wrap my custom view in a `RelativeLayout` like this:

```
((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container)).addView(myView);
```

And this is the layout file that I am using:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test"
        android:layout_below="@+id/container"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that the `TextView` is at the top of the screen instead of being below the `RelativeLayout` (with the `@+id/container` id). As it will be without the `android:layout_below` property.

It behaves like my custom view (`MyView`) does not *set* its dimensions. I tried to use the `setLayoutParams()` but it did not change anything.

Comment: I don't get it; why the `TextView` can't be below the `RelativeLayout` with the `@+id/container` id? (I did a typo in my post, I have corrected it)

Comment: @FrankN.Stein `container` is not the parent of the `TextView` in his layout XML.

Comment: Does your custom `MyView` set its own layout height?  (Given that the height of it's container is `wrap_content` it needs to.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your container view is inflated and laid out before your custom view is added to it and so gets a height of 0 since it has no content.  After you add it to its container, a relayout is forced at which point the container asks the child view to measure itself. Since the height of the container is `wrap_content`, the child needs to report a specific height at this point.  My guess is that your `MyView` class is not doing this.

An easy thing to do in order to set the height of your `MyView` objects is to override and implement the `onMeasure()` method.

Comment: It works. You were right, I had to implement the `onMeasure` method. Thanks